# find all substring that starts and ends with specific characters

Tags: python, regex

I have to find all substring is a string $a$ that starts with M and ends with _
I tried

```
a = 'ICQLEFAKNASFSVSNVSKKNGEFSHAHEQDQNLRLIARQR_RSADGTPNKVNTSNVRCSTPIFGNNPFAQSLAHREYGHEGENVQCRPCGSLPSRKCQRNVHPKQQQQQQHQHCHRNSA_APAIRAAQAAGGDNSSRSEK_RAAAARIPVNDDSNMETSLALESRRRNHQSIEPLVRG_PCRQCNNRFSCTWAWRTM_PISNEAHIDLVELASLERADNC_NRPKYR_GLQPYHGNCSTLFK_IAGMSIFYHNTKILKCFM_RETL_F_NYVDN_VGILELL_KTWNS_SSSFLALNNKL_YTNKNLCNS_NVAPKLIYKN_IYFVS_QIA'$

b=re.findall('^M_$',a)
```

it gives an empty list 
I want the output to be like that

```
['METSLALESRRRNHQSIEPLVRG_', 'M_', 'M_']
```

Comment: `re.findall('M.*?_', a)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> re.findall('M.*?_', a)
['METSLALESRRRNHQSIEPLVRG_', 'M_', 'MSIFYHNTKILKCFM_']
```

Or, if the results must not contain embedded `M` characters:

```
>>> re.findall('M[^M]*?_', a)
['METSLALESRRRNHQSIEPLVRG_', 'M_', 'M_']
```