# Python regex from single symbol to any alphanumeric symbols or EOL

Tags: python, regex, split

```
import re
text123 = "test, test12, #test3,  #test4 - : test555"
print(re.findall(r"#.*[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]",  text123)) 
# expected ['#test3', '#test4']
# result ['#test3,  #test4 -']

print(re.findall(r"#.*[^a-zA-Z\d]",  text123)) 
# expected ['#test3', '#test4']
# result ['#test3,  #test4 - : ']est3,  #test4 - ']

print(re.findall(r"#.*?[^a-zA-Z\d]",  text123)) 
# result ['#test3,', '#test4 ']
# what would I like- ['#test3', '#test4']
```

I tried
[find all substring that starts and ends with specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164765/find-all-substring-that-starts-and-ends-with-specific-characters)
[find all substring that starts and ends with specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164765/find-all-substring-that-starts-and-ends-with-specific-characters)

and other links \ manuals \ etc - no way

Comment: Use non-greedy `.*?`

Comment: Or change `.*` to `[a-zA-Z\d\s:]*`

Comment: You have not stated the question precisely and unambiguously. If it is, "match all strings that contain only letters and digits, which begin with a letter, end with a digit, with no letter preceded by a digit", then match `[a-zA-Z]+\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use alphanumerics instead of dot symbol if you try to find alphanumerics? Put what you want, avoid what you don't want.

```
import re
text123 = "test, test12, #test3,  #test4 - : test555"
print(re.findall(r"#[a-zA-Z\d]+",  text123)) 
# expected ['#test3', '#test4']
# result ['#test3,  #test4']
```

Comment: and for cyrillic - text124 = "мама мыла раму #рама #mama8 #прочее"
print(re.findall(r"#[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яa-я]+",  text124))

Comment: This is out of the scope of the question. Still you can find answers here, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448274/russian-symbols-in-re-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206499/match-letter-in-any-language